# Manifest merger failed while integrating payumoney

Tags: android, android-studio, payment-gateway, payumoney

I am integrating payumoney in my android application. I have read docs and see video for integration i.e < https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gnQ0IF3XniM&t=740s >. Problem is when i am trying to import module dependency it gives me error that manifest merger failed with multiple error.

```
 C:\Users\amit\Desktop\New folder (3)\SalwarTales-master\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:22:9-38 Error:
Attribute application@icon value=(@drawable/logo) from AndroidManifest.xml:22:9-38
is also present at [:sdkui] AndroidManifest.xml:20:9-43 value=(@mipmap/ic_launcher).
Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:icon"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:20:5-72:19 to override.

 C:\Users\amit\Desktop\New folder (3)\SalwarTales-master\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:26:9-43 Error:
Attribute application@theme value=(@style/NoActionBar) from AndroidManifest.xml:26:9-43
is also present at [:sdkui] AndroidManifest.xml:22:9-40 value=(@style/AppTheme).
Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:theme"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:20:5-72:19 to override.
```

Comment: Copy your code here, and remove the images.

Comment: Please post gradleconsole log

Comment: It's not going anywhere. just become selected @pavya

Comment: What are those **multiple errors** that you've mentioned?

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

Comment: i am getting this error

Comment: Warning:The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (23.0.2) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (26.0.2) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.0.1.
Android SDK Build Tools 26.0.2 will be used.
To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.

Comment: There is a gradle console on bottom right corner of android studio. please post the error from that

Comment: updated code. please take a look

Answer (score 1):

finally did it. very silly mistake. I was using Different launcher icon and app theme in both modules.